# Fetch mp3 and aac songs from iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, media-queries, mp3, aac

Can we fetch an array of song data for all the songs from iphone song library which are having media type as mp3 and aac only. I have been searching for this but didn't found anything productive.

Answer (score 0):

There two framework are needed.

-> MPMediaLibrary, MPMediaQuery

And Code is->

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Logging items from a generic query...");

NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];

for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery) {

   NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];

   NSLog (@"%@", songTitle);

}
```

Comment: but this only gives the title of the track. no information regarding its type.
I want only mp3 and aac format songs.